# Limiting my UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have the following code and it works just fine, but I can't really explain it to myself.  My goal was to drag my `UIView` from the bottom and have it stop moving when the bottom of the `UIView` reaches the *center of the screen*.  The code does just that, but I'm still confused by how the limit i set `(newCenter.y >= 0 && newCenter.y <= 284)` works.

My perception of whats happening is that when I begin dragging the `UIView` from the very bottom towards the top of the screen, my `newCenter.y` is constantly changing (decreasing) as I drag upwards.  But what makes it stop when the bottom of the view being dragged reaches the center of the screen?  The view stops dragging way before I even get close to 0.

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    if (newCenter.y >= 0 && newCenter.y <= 284) {
        recognizer.view.center = newCenter;
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, without any knowledge of the context of how your view and superview are laid out...

if you want the bottom of the view to stop at the centre, then you'd want 284 - (self.view.frame.size.height/2) right?

Comment: My `UIView` has the same width and height of the screen 284X568.  So once my `newCenter.y` is less than or equal to 284, then this code `recognizer.view.center = newCenter` is executed?  What makes the `UIView` stop moving up?